# RMI ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, rmi, jmx, classnotfoundexception, rmiregistry

I have problem with rmiregistry. I'm getting below error:

```
Cannot bind to URL [rmi://........]: javax.naming.NamingException [Root exception is java.rmi.UnexpectedException: undeclared checked exception; nested exception is: 
                java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find class (javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub) at codebase ()]
```

I checked, class exist in the classpath.

I used java 1.6 on linux. I started `rmiregistry 6667`.
Has anyone met with this error?

Comment: Does it work on the standard port 1099?

Comment: On the standard port is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> class exist in the classpath.

In your *JVM's* classpath. It is also needed on the Registry's classpath, and the client's.

Comment: I resolve this problem. Wrong rmiregistry file was invoke, not from java but from usr/bin/

Comment: how to add class in Registry's classpath?