# Why the RMI client needs to have the Stub in his classpath?

Tags: java, rmi

*Note: I changed the question title to be more precise*

Here is my question: When using RMI to communicate between a client and a server, does the **client** needs to have the `Stub` in his classpath, or does this `Stub` should only be on server side?

---

*Note, the "full" story:*

I am currently working on a web-application that calls a calculation engine. The communication between these 2 elements is made using **RMI**.

Here is Maven structure of the project:

```
my-project
 +- core
 +- web-application
 +- engine
```

Both `web-application` and `engine` have a dependency on `core`.

In `core` module, I've defined an interface:

```
public interface MyEngine extends java.rmi.Remote {

    MyResults calculate() throws RemoteException;

}
```

In `engine` module (which is the **server** on the RMI point of view), I define the implementation of this interface:

```
public class MyEngineImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyEngine {

    public MyResults calculate() throws RemoteException {
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MyEngine engine = new MyEngineImpl();
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1418);
        registry.rebind("my-engine", engine);
    }

}
```

Finally, on the `web-application`, I wrote a class that calls the engine module, using the interface of `core`:

```
public class RemoteEngineFacade {

    public MyResults callCalculate() throws RemoteException {
        Registry localisation = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("url-of-engine", 1418);
        MyEngine engine = (LiquidityEngine) localisation.lookup("my-engine");
        return engine.calculate();
    }

}
```

The RMI compilation is made by the `rmic` Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rmic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>rmi compilation</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>rmic</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

(note that this plugin definition is made on **each** module)

Now, after deploying the application, when the `web-application` is calling the `engine`, I get the following error **on the web-application logs**:

```
2012-03-12 09:42:37 ERROR [xxx.RemoteEngineFacade] Engine is unable to respond to the request
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx.MyEngineImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at xxx.RemoteEngineFacade.callCalculate(RemoteEngineFacade.java:50)
    ...
```

I don't get why it is looking for the Stub on the `web-application` side, as normally the Stub has only to be located on the RMI server (the `engine` in my context).

Do you have any idea where is my problem?

Thanks.

---

**Edit**: Setting a security manager, as explained in Riddhish.Chaudhari answer did solve the issue. The only difference is that I don't have the *no security manager: RMI class loader disabled* message in the stacktrace anymore...

---

**Edit 2**: If I copy the engine.jar in my `WEB-INF/lib`, then the communication is made correctly. But I should not have to add the engine library in my web-application...

Comment: possible duplicate of [RMI ClassNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387031/rmi-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: It seems to be the same problem, but in the other question, no answer was accepted, and the user indicates that it was just a configuration issue...

Comment: and that's exactly what it is, a configuration issue. The class named is not available at the client. It has to be there so the client can use it. That's what it's *for.* Unless you are using dynamic stubs, which you aren't, or you wouldn't be getting that error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. [In this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#21), it is said that

> As of the J2SE 5.0 release, stub classes for remote objects no longer
>   need to be pregenerated using the rmic stub compiler, unless the
>   remote object needs to support clients running in pre-5.0 VMs

As I am working with Java 6, I decided to *simply* remove the `rmic` tasks in my `pom.xml` files... and it worked!

Maybe the presence of a `Stub` in the server (my engine) creates some confusion for the JVM, which produces the error I got...

Answer (score -2):

You are not using a security manager:

Have you got a policy file (mypolicy.policy):

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

and run your program using

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/some/path/myplicy.policy MyClass
```

Use below link to for complete example of how to use security policy permission

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javarmi/javarmi.html

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will check that. Do I need to also add in my code the `System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());` line ?

Comment: -1. None of this would make any difference unless he also started using the codebase feature. Not an answer.